# Is there any possible use PureRenderMixin in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use `PureRenderMixin` optimize performance through `shouldComponentUpdate`,
but after `npm i react-addons-pure-render-mixin --save`, I find that I can't call `PureRenderMixin` correctly.

I follow [react document](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) ES6 step.

```
import PureRenderMixin from 'react-addons-pure-render-mixin';

class FooComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.shouldComponentUpdate = PureRenderMixin.shouldComponentUpdate.bind(this);
  }
}
```

And always get `Unable to resolve module react-addons-pure-render-mixin` error.

Is there any possible use `PureRenderMixin` in react native? If so, how should I fix it?

Comment: Did you install `react-addons-pure-render-mixin`? It sounds like it's not installed.

Comment: @CarlVitullo  yes, I install `react-addons-pure-render-mixin`, my clerical error

Answer (score 0):

You may need import reactMixin from 'react-mixin'; The whole solution would be something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import reactMixin from 'react-mixin';
import PureRenderMixin from 'react-addons-pure-render-mixin';

import Styles from './styles';

export default class Loading extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={Styles.container}>
          <Text>Hello world!!!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

reactMixin(Loading.prototype, PureRenderMixin);
```

Comment: For further reading, you may apply decorator @ onto the function reactMixin. Hope this helpful.